# Copy most recent/last sheets in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a button that copies my most recent 7 sheets. This code obviously works for the first time but then it continues to copy the first seven sheets not the most recent 7 (which makes sense as I have 1-7 entered). I have tried to put negatives in front of the numbers but then I get an error. Is there a way to get the most recent/last 7 sheets to copy instead of my starting sheets. Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)).Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not the most elegant solution, but this should do it

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim i As Long
Dim wsCount As Long

Dim a(1 To 7) As Long   'change here if you want other than 7
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'change workbook here if you want
wsCount = wb.Worksheets.Count 

    'creates an array of the last n worksheets (7 in this case, as determined above)
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        a(i) = wsCount - i + 1
    Next

    'copies the worksheets
    wb.Worksheets(a).Copy After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
```

Just curious, why are you copying it to the same workbook? If to another workbook you should stipulate that in the code

Comment: Thanks jblack. it's a progress estimate with 7 pages that gets copied every month so we keep it all in the same workbook.

Comment: All good. Does the above code answer your question? If so mark it as answered :)